# Set up Mercurial for command completion in a Windows console

Tags: windows, mercurial, console, tab-completion

Is there a way to setup Mercurial to get command completion when working from console on Windows?

I'd like to have something similar to `git bash`, but for mercurial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People in [#mercurial](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial) tells me that there's nothing like this for `cmd.exe`. But I found a repository with [Mercurial tab completion support for PowerShell](http://poshhg.codeplex.com/).

An alternative is to run Cygwin and use the Bash or Zsh shell from there. Then you can use the normal [Bash completion](http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/contrib/bash_completion) and [Zsh completion](http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/contrib/zsh_completion) scripts.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I went with the posh-hg and it does exactly what I need